# What does the colour of the 'schedule' column in the airflow UI mean?

Tags: python, airflow

Can anyone help me understand the 'schedule' column in the airflow web UI.

[image]

Why does it sometimes colour the icon red? Is that showing the scheduler is down? It seems like this is the case, but I couldn't find any explanation definitive explanation anywhere about this column.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's related to that DAG reaching the DAG run limit. The DAG run limit defaults to `core:max_active_runs_per_dag`, but can be overridden by the `max_active_runs` parameter when creating a DAG.

If you hover over the red label, it should actually show you the number of currently active runs and the limit. Clicking it should also take you to the list of DAG runs for that DAG, which is a useful view to override the state if necessary (i.e. set every run as failed).

Given that your schedule is `None`, I assume you may have kicked off too many manual runs of the DAG at once or need to bump up the limit.